# How is IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH used?

Tags: c++, windows, ioctl, ata

I've been working on creating a program to send (preferrably arbitrary) ATA commands, and so far, the only option I've found in Windows is [IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559309(v=vs.85).aspx) and a related struct, [ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551323(v=vs.85).aspx) using C++.

Unfortunately, I've been finding the documentation to be lacking for those who don't already know what they're doing. Here's what I haven't figured out:

- How is `IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH` used in a statement?
- Where do you put the ATA command to send?
- `ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX.DataTransferLength` should be the size of the data buffer, in bytes. Is that the struct + the ATA command, or just the command?
- How do you select which drive the command is going to?
- Where does the response from the drive go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little too long for a comment, so I'm posting it as an answer, but please be aware that it is largely educated guesswork.

*How is IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH used in a statement?*

This one's easy.  Like all control codes, it is sent using [the DeviceIoControl function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx).

*Where do you put the ATA command to send?*

I'm unfamiliar with ATA, but my guess is the "command register", i.e., `CurrentTaskFile[6]`.  I imagine that you could find some documentation on the ATA protocol that should clear this up.

*`ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX.DataTransferLength` should be the size of the data buffer, in bytes. Is that the struct + the ATA command, or just the command?*

The documentation says

> If the embedded ATA command is a write operation, the size of the input buffer should be the sum of sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX) and the value in the DataTransferLength member of ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX.

So `DataTransferLength` definitely does not include the length of the `ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX` structure.

*How do you select which drive the command is going to?*

Presumably this is determined by the device handle that you pass to DeviceIoControl().

*Where does the response from the drive go?*

Into the DeviceIoControl() output buffer.

Comment: This was all true. Thank you!